# Sum Elements of a List in R - For

Tags: r

I have a list (mylist) of 110 items.

```
length(mylist)

#[1] 110
```

The elements within the lists are descriptions.
I'm trying sum the elements of the entire list (basically counting the words in each description).

This provides a total for the first element.

```
length(mylist[[1]]) 

#[1] 162
```

Instead of repeating that 110 times, what is the best way to sum all 110 elements? Would a `for` statement work?
Thanks.

Comment: Coud you please add an example of the data?

Comment: try: `sum(lengths(list))`

Comment: `lengths(list)`      ?

Comment: just to point out that calling your variable `list` is not a good idea, since it's shadowing the `R` function `list()`

Comment: use `dput` to provide an example of your data set, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More generally, use `lapply` to apply a function to each element of a list:

```
lapply(list, length)
```

Comment: and `sum(unlist(lapply(list, length)))` if you want to sum them all

Comment: sum(lengths(list))

Comment: For completeness, `do.call(sum, lapply(list, length))` is also possible, though I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Thanks so much for the input! Novice here; was having trouble conceptualizing how I was going to do this.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use:

`sum(unlist(mylist))`

Comment: This will give the sum of the content not count elements or words what the asker requested. It will fail if the elements are not numeric.

Answer (score 2):

Try this and it will sum all the entries inside the list:

```
do.call(sum, mylist)
```

Ensure that `mylist` is in the list format.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to determine element (word) wise count of each component (description) in your list , use
`Reduce("+",mylist)`